# Blender used 40 GB of my storage

Tags: rendering

I was rendering an animation and it was supposed to be done on the D: drive. After finishing rendering on the C: drive, Blender had used 40 GB.

I can't find these files anywhere.

Comment: C:\TEMP or C:\Windows\TEMP are probably good places to look. Look for directories named something like blender_1Af6OV or similar. I cannot confirm this, since I'm not anywhere a windows machine, hence the comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Windirstat is a program that will analyze your drive and provide a graphical display telling you what folders on your drive are taking up the most space.  A 40gb folder should stand out.

Comment: A _Temp_ folder like @TitaniusAnglesmith suggested might be a good start, but the default path Blender uses is C:\tmp\